# Symfony2 integer type and NotBlank constraints are triggered at the same time

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints, assertion

I'm trying to validate a field in a form with the NotBlank and Type constraints. My problem is that when I enter a value that doesn't match the type both error messages are displayed. I have seen other answers that suggested that the field type should be changed to text.
Unfortunately, changing the field type to text and leaving the constraint for integer type will raise the validation error all the time.
Does anyone know of any solution to this problem? I'm using Symfony 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

What type do you have assigned in the Entity's property that matches this field?